# Can I raise a lawsuit against a bitcoin wallet provider?

Tags: legal

I think I'm not only one on this boat. I have bitfix bitcoin wallet, it's installed on my phone as it's phone's app anyway, it's got option to create login and password so obviously it connects to the online server managed by bitfix where user's accounts with funds are kept so you can use it on a different phone if needed.

Short story: it was working well until I've noticed the funds from the wallet gone and found a transaction which I didn't do at all, also the transaction was at the night time and my phone was powered off at the time. the bitfix support said that many accounts have been hacked and coins got stolen from their wallets.

WTF? Bitfix, who manages so many accounts do not have a simple security and encryption? Also they do not hold any responsibility for this at all and will not refund my funds. Stuff them, I didn't have much about $100 was on my wallet but it's not the point as you understand, I'm a bit pissed off with this and suspect the Bitfix's admins were involved in this as they do not want to investigate further and do not want to refund anything, also admins could have access to the private keys info and be able to withdraw funds from the user's wallets as the wallet's info stored online. Any thoughts on this?